# $(SUDO_USER) Variable inside debian package makefile

Tags: debian, packaging

So I'm making a debian package, but I'm having trouble with doing some permissions settings that I want to do after all the files have been copied over. It's a networked application and uses libpcap. So normally it would require root privileges, but that's a big security problem. (Since any compromise in my program would mean full root access to the attacker) So instead, we go the route of creating a group with pcap permissions granted and then add the installing user to that group.

In the makefile it looks like:

```
setcap 'CAP_NET_RAW+eip CAP_NET_ADMIN+eip' /usr/bin/myProgram
groupadd -f myGroup
usermod -a -G myGroup $(SUDO_USER)
```

Which totally works fine if you run "sudo make install". But when I try to do this inside a postinst script in a debian package, I get this:

```
var/lib/dpkg/info/myProgram-1.0.postinst: line 13: SUDO_USER: command not found
Usage: usermod [options] LOGIN

Options:
  -c, --comment COMMENT         new value of the GECOS field
  -d, --home HOME_DIR           new home directory for the user account
  -e, --expiredate EXPIRE_DATE  set account expiration date to EXPIRE_DATE
  -f, --inactive INACTIVE       set password inactive after expiration
                                to INACTIVE
  -g, --gid GROUP               force use GROUP as new primary group
  -G, --groups GROUPS           new list of supplementary GROUPS
  -a, --append                  append the user to the supplemental GROUPS
                                mentioned by the -G option without removing
                                him/her from other groups
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -l, --login NEW_LOGIN         new value of the login name
  -L, --lock                    lock the user account
  -m, --move-home               move contents of the home directory to the
                                new location (use only with -d)
  -o, --non-unique              allow using duplicate (non-unique) UID
  -p, --password PASSWORD       use encrypted password for the new password
  -s, --shell SHELL             new login shell for the user account
  -u, --uid UID                 new UID for the user account
  -U, --unlock                  unlock the user account
  -Z, --selinux-user            new SELinux user mapping for the user account
```

Clearly because the $(SUDO_USER) variable is empty. How else is this done? Do I have to prompt the user for his/her username? That sounds awfully ugly. 
Or maybe you're just not supposed to do this kind of configuration in a debian package?

(IE: Wireshark has the same issue here, but they seem to just leave it up to the user, and not mess with permissions at installation at all.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it right: You aren't supposed to know the username of the "installing user", since there might be none. Imagine your package is run by `apt-cron`, then the whole concept of "installing user" makes no sense.

Add a system-wide group with the appropriate permissions and leave a message in the installation log that users need to be added to the group. Or, alternatively, use a pre-existing system group that might suit your purpose.

Answer (score -1):

You definitely can get username of installing user, just remove those braces, because bash interprets that as a function

```
#!/bin/sh
# postinst script
usermod -a -G myGroup $SUDO_USER
# Do everythhing that you could imagine
```

But you must remember that:

1) This wouldn't work in some GUI applications, such as Ubuntu Software Center

2) It's definitely a bad practice. All packages must set up their user-specific environment on  first launch.